# How to rewrite commit authors after subgit import already completed?

Tags: git, subgit

I imported large svn repository using Subgit. Later i noticed that svn revisions only had e-mail addresses while git usually also has user.names.

There is special file `authors.txt` for subgit which contains mapping from svn users to git users. But in order to use it i will have to reimport the whole repository again, which will take too much time.

I just want to fix authors of all commits in already imported repository, having mapping file of the following format:

```
example1@example.com = John Doe <example1@example.com>
example2@example.com = Jack Doe <example2@example.com>
...
```

How can i easily rewrite git commit history according to above list either with git or subgit?

Comment: Found this script https://gist.github.com/stigkj/1451142

Comment: Note that after that script continuous synchronization will stop working because SubGit keeps SHA1<->revision number pairs in its internal structures and after the script SHA1 will be different. But for just conversion this solution is ok.